# Javascript: $('body:contains("")') with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I want to use `$('body:contains("")')` for searching part of a html code.

For example:

```
var thing = $('body:contains("Web</a></td></tr>")').text()
    if(thing) {
        alert(thing);
    }
else{
    alert("not found")
        }
```

This code always alerts "not found".

Is it possible to search a part of a html code and alert if found?

Thank you...

Comment: Beware that you may ***see*** "Web</a></td></tr>", when inspecting with your browser, but the actual code may contain whitespace or not even have closing tags!   Even if the source is "Web</a></td></tr>" **now**, stuff like that can break very easily on pages that you do not control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use selectors to look for HTML fragments, as no element contains the HTML fragment as text.

You can put the elements in the selector as elements, and look only for the text part of your HTML fragement:

```
var thing = $('body tr > td > a:contains("Web")').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

`:contains()` searches text, not markup. To find an element whose HTML contents (`innerHTML`) includes a given string, you can use `.filter()` like:

```
$('body').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.indexOf('Web</a></td></tr>') > -1;
});
```

Comment: Yes. However, this would be quite slow :(

Comment: @toby, for the *example* (`$('body')`), it would be quite quick. For a large set of elements, it would be no slower than an equivalent jQuery selector (in fact it would probably be faster, being that it doesn't have to parse the selector). *If* it's really necessary to check for the string `"Web</a></td></tr>"`, then the only faster method than this would be to use `document.body.innerHTML` instead, but then it wouldn't be general purpose (it couldn't be used to filter larger sets of elements).

Answer (score 1):

`:contains` doesn't check html. You could instead do:

```
if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('Web</a></td></tr>') > -1) {
    // whatever
}
```